# Rate this app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used the [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) class to add 'rate my app' functionality. I have added my app bundle ID. But when I run the app it shows "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". Please help me out to find the issue.

This is the code I'm using:

```
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSUserDefaults *times=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int test=[[times objectForKey:@"time"]intValue];
    NSLog(@"test..:%d",test);
    if (test >=5) {

        [iRate sharedInstance].applicationBundleID = @"com.01Synergy";
        [iRate sharedInstance].onlyPromptIfLatestVersion = NO;

        //enable preview mode
        [iRate sharedInstance].previewMode = YES;
    }
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSUserDefaults *times=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    int time=[[times objectForKey:@"time"]intValue];

    if (time<5) {
        time++;
        [times setInteger:time forKey:@"time"];

    }

}
```

Comment: Is your app on the AppStore already?

Comment: In my app I am giving the reference of another app which is already available in store.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dZezppBm  I want to open the iRate alert when user opens the app 5th time

Comment: @NAZIK please check this code pastebin.com/dZezppBm

Comment: In the future, please edit your post with the code. I've done that for you here.

Comment: Check your internet connection!

Comment: Replace `@"com.01Synergy"` with your BundleID?

Comment: its bundle id I have used in my released app.

Comment: One thing more comes in my mind again and again that why I using iRate or Appirater for rating our app? Can't we make our custom alert view for rating? May be I asked some thing wrong but It would be good if someone explain these classes benefit.

Comment: The benefits are; You do not have to implement it yourself!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not familiar with iRate, I often uses [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater). It is **extremely easy** to implement. Simple call

```
[Appirater setAppId:@"380245121"];    // Change for your "Your APP ID"
[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0];     // Days from first entered the app until prompt
[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:5];     // Number of uses until prompt
[Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:2]; // Days until reminding if the user taps "remind me"
//[Appirater setDebug:YES];           // If you set this to YES it will display all the time
```

to have it show after the user have entered the app the 5th time!

Say you have done `[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:5]` and `[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:2]` it means that the time from first app entry has to be 2 days (or more) **AND** the number of app uses (number of times the application entered foreground/launched) has to be 5 times (or more).

Sample code for your purpose:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [Appirater setAppId:@"380245121"];    // Change for your "Your APP ID"
    [Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0];     // Days from first entered the app until prompt
    [Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:5];     // Number of uses until prompt
    [Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:2]; // Days until reminding if the user taps "remind me"
    //[Appirater setDebug:YES];           // If you set this to YES it will display all the time

    //... Perhaps do stuff

    [Appirater appLaunched:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
    [Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES];
}
```

If your app is out on App Store you can find the app ID in the URL:

[image]

If it is not yet released you can find it by going to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) ->> tapping "Manage Your Apps" -->> tapping your app. You app ID will be seen here
[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: will you please explain its parameters. How it is working? setDaysUntilPrompt etc

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: I have added the Appirater classes in my app and alert comes successfully when I opens the app 5th time. When the second time alert will show? @Filip

Comment: The alert will only be shown again if the user taps the "Remind me later" button. Glad it worked!

Comment: @Filip Suppose user clicked on the rate this app button but didn't gave rating to app. In that case alert will show again or not.

Comment: @MinkleGarg I do not thinks so, no! BUT I can't say I'm 100% sure. Look in the code of the Appirater and if that doesn't help why don't you try the [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/appirater) of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your bundle ID.
Currently it's set to @"com.01Synergy" but it's your developer ID.
Bundle ID you can see in *iOS Application Target* section in `Xcode`.

Btw, I also use iRate and there is no need to use `[iRate sharedInstance].applicationBundleID = @"com.01Synergy";`, so just comment it.

Comment: how to prompt the alert only when user opens the app 5th time?

Comment: @MinkleGarg [iRate sharedInstance].usesUntilPrompt = 15;

Comment: @MinkleGarg And set days also [iRate sharedInstance].daysUntilPrompt = 0;